# A WCF webservice and the Application Settings horror

Tags: wcf, web-services, web-config, application-settings

I have written a WCF service that I am hosting in IIS7 as a webservice.  I have 8 application scope settings that I have defined in the WCF service library project in the app.config.  I want to make these settings available to the network admins so that they can be changed as necessary without me having to open the solution, change the setting, recompile, re-deploy.

Using the app.config, that is case, because aparently the app.config is somehow incorporated into the built dll which is referenced by the webservice project.

So, I am trying to put these settings in the web.config.  I have seen many sites that say simply to add the settings thusly:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="LDAPServerAddress" value="LDAP:/192.168.1.96/" />
    <add key="ClientsOU" value="OU=Clients/" />
    <add key="UsersOU" value="OU=Users" />
</appSettings>
```

which, upon running the service I am informed that User-Scoped settings are not allowed.  I knew that, and that is why I attempted to create Application-Scoped settings (reference the above XML tag `<appSettings>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using what you have shown above.

Make sure `<appSettings>` isn't contained in some other node other than the `<configuration>` node in your web.config.

I read out the values like this:

```
 var userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USER_NAME"];
```

Check the location of your appSettings node and compare how you're reading values with how I am above.

If that still doesn't work, I suggest eliminating everything else and creating a stupidly simple service with just one app setting.  Set it up as you've shown above and see if the really simple service works as expected.

If so, you've got a problem elsewhere.  If not, share the code for the simple service and we'll figure out what's going on.

Comment: the <appSettings> node should be under the <configuration> node right?

Comment: Yup - sorry - forgot to mark those bits as code - now my answer should make a bit more sense.

Comment: Minimal webservice worked as advertized.  My webservice did not.  Still don't know what is going on in there.  For now I am going to hardcode the settings and get to them later.  I have to get this out the door.  Despite the fact that this did not work for me, I will accept it as the answer because it falls in line with everything else I have read.  I will pick up again later on.  Thanks for the help!